# OpenCMS - 301 redirect

Tags: java, opencms

Is there any easy way to configure permanent redirects (301) on openCMS? I would like to forward some of my old page urls to their new location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found UrlRewriteFilter (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to be quite nice to work with and solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSP-template which does nothing else than to send a 301 Permanent Redirect. I did that and it works.

Depending on your requirements you can put the new URL in a property or automatically modify the old URL in the JSP-template.

Comment: I tried to put it in JSP on OpenCms 7.5.2 but it does not work, nothing happens. 
<%
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( "Location", "https://www.domain.com/newPage.html");
response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
%>

Comment: Update: make sure you use the OpenCms specific methods for that: http://lists.opencms.org/pipermail/opencms-dev/2009q4/033082.html